# How can i get only certain columns with ImportData from CSV url

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to get certain columns with ImportData function from csv url.

Answer (score 3):

there are various ways like only 1 column:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTDATA("url");; 5)
```

or few columns:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("url"); 9^9; 3)
```

or selected columns:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTDATA("url"); "select Col1,Col5,Col3")
```

---

### update:

```
function IMPORTCSV() {
  // Provide the full URL of the CSV file below.
  var csvUrl = 'https://example.com/data.csv';
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
 }
```

and then:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTCSV();; 2)
```

or just:

```
=IMPORTCSV()
```

Comment: i am getting still this error "Resource at url contents exceeded maximum size."

Comment: @Efex and standalone IMPORTDATA will import stuff?

Comment: same error. That's why I wanted to try this method.

Comment: @Efex in that case try with script. answer updated

Comment: I am getting this error; TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
IMPORTCSV @ Code.gs:7